# Silverlight AG_E_UNKOWN_ERROR UserControl Apps.xml Template

Tags: xaml, templates, silverlight, user-controls

Ive created a simple usercontrol and even though the app runs ok applying the template to

I am defining the Control Template here

App.xaml

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             x:Class="ResourcesCountDown.App"
             >
    <Application.Resources>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="myWindowTemplate">
            <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Background="Black" Width="50" Height="50">
                <ContentPresenter Name="Content"></ContentPresenter>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

My UserControl Test.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="ResourcesCountDown.Test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Width="100" Height="100" >

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Button Name="myButton" Template="{StaticResource myWindowTemplate}" Foreground="White" Content="CLICK" ></Button>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

My page where the user control is being used and the page where the AG E UNKOWN_ERROR occurs.
If I remove applying the template from test.xaml and remove the `Template="{StaticResource myWindowTemplate}"` the error goes away, so I know its something BAD in my template definition?

Mainpage.xaml

```
<UserControl  x:Class="ResourcesCountDown.Mainpage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:ResourcesCountDown="clr-namespace:ResourcesCountDown" 
    xmlns:sliverlightControls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit" 

    Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Name="mainPage"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" ShowGridLines="False" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" CornerRadius="5">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFAA01"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFD6900" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <Grid x:Name="TopBannerGrid">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <ResourcesCountDown:LogoControl Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                <ResourcesCountDown:MenuControl Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" x:Name="menu" Margin="0,-30,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <sliverlightControls:WrapPanel Width="900" Height="600" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >

            <ResourcesCountDown:noteControl Width="200" Height="200" headingText="Whats it about?" Margin="10"
                noteText="We have one planet with finite resources. This web site was created to try and express the resource consumption.">

            </ResourcesCountDown:noteControl>

            <ResourcesCountDown:noteControl Width="200" Height="200" headingText="Latest News" Margin="10"
                noteText="This week we have see some many new news in just a short time">                                    
              </ResourcesCountDown:noteControl>



            <ResourcesCountDown:RSSFeed Width="600" Height="200" Margin="10" headingText="Hot News"/>

            <ResourcesCountDown:datagridControl Width="600" Height="100" x:Name="theDataGrid" Margin="10" headingText="Stats" > </ResourcesCountDown:datagridControl>

            <ResourcesCountDown:Test></ResourcesCountDown:Test>        

        </sliverlightControls:WrapPanel>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a TargetType="Grid" on your `<ControlTemplate>`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="myWindowTemplate TargetType="Grid">
```

....

Also, Grid isn't a ContentControl so I don't think the ContentPresenter you put in the template will behave the way you expect - it could even be causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, from the code you've posted, your TargetType should be Button because you're applying the template to  button.